# How do I use regex to sort this string

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm trying to sort this string of data by the date at the beginning of the string, but I'm not sure exactly how to split, join, and sort it using this regex. And yes I'm using `re.MULTILINE`.

regex that matches the date at the beginning of the line:

```
^ [0-9]{4}
```

Example of the string I need to be sorted:

```
 string = ''' 
 2013 this is data 3 (more data from 3)
 2016 this is data 6 (more data from 6)
 2011 this is data 1 (more data from 1)
 2012 this is data 2 (more data from 2)
 2014 this is data 4 (more data from 4)'''
```

What I want it to look like:

```
 string = ''' 
 2016 this is data 6 (more data from 6)
 2014 this is data 4 (more data from 4)
 2013 this is data 3 (more data from 3)
 2012 this is data 2 (more data from 2)
 2011 this is data 1 (more data from 1)'''
```

Comment: why are you using regex for this? use `str.split(' ')` to split it on spaces.

Comment: Just wondering if you actually need regex since you're just reading the first space-delimited word on each line.

Comment: I need to keep the strings in order, if I sort just the dates how am I going to keep the dates aligned with the correct data? I guess I'm not sure how to do this can you provide an example?

Comment: You can extract the first part and then create a dictionary using the date as key and the string as value. Then the easiest way is to use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your input data is one long string. You can use `str.splitlines()` on the string to get it line by line.

```
multiline_str = """ 2013 this is data 3 (blah blah blah)
 2016 this is data 6 (blah blah blah)
 2011 this is data 1 (blah blah blah)
 2012 this is data 2 (blah blah blah)
 2014 this is data 4 (blah blah blah)
"""
sorted(multiline_str.splitlines(), key=lambda x: x[:5], reverse=True)
```

Will produce this:

```
[' 2016 this is data 6 (blah blah blah)', 
 ' 2014 this is data 4 (blah blah blah)',
 ' 2013 this is data 3 (blah blah blah)', 
 ' 2012 this is data 2 (blah blah blah)', 
 ' 2011 this is data 1 (blah blah blah)', 
 ' ']
```

Comment: That is a good observation, it didn't occur to me that this might be one big string. You should add `reverse=True` to the sort though, that is what OP has,.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to use regex in your code to sort the string, you have to go through the process of:

- Splitting the string base on newline character.
- Use the `sorted()` method to sort the list base on the captured number in the string.
- Use the string `.join()` method to convert the list to string.
  e.g

```py
import re

longtext = """2013 this is data 3 (more data from 3)
2016 this is data 6 (more data from 6)
2011 this is data 1 (more data from 1)
2012 this is data 2 (more data from 2)
2014 this is data 4 (more data from 4)
"""

data = longtext.splitlines()
data = sorted(data , key = lambda v: re.search(r'^[\t ]*[\d]{4,}', v)[0], reverse=True)

new = '\n'.join(data)
print(new)
```

Output:

```
2016 this is data 6 (more data from 6)
2014 this is data 4 (more data from 4)
2013 this is data 3 (more data from 3)
2012 this is data 2 (more data from 2)
2011 this is data 1 (more data from 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

use a regular expression to find the year then let the year become the dictionary key then sort the dictionary keys descending.  Output the value by get and the key of the sorted key values.

```
 longtext = """2013 this is data 3 (more data from 3)
 2016 this is data 6 (more data from 6)
 2011 this is data 1 (more data from 1)
 2012 this is data 2 (more data from 2)
 2014 this is data 4 (more data from 4)"""

 data = longtext.splitlines()
 dct={}
 for x in data:
      dct[(re.search(r'\d{4}',x))[0]]=x

 for i in sorted (dct.keys(),reverse=True) :  
      print(dct.get(i))
```

output:

```
2016 this is data 6 (more data from 6)
2014 this is data 4 (more data from 4)
2013 this is data 3 (more data from 3)
2012 this is data 2 (more data from 2)
2011 this is data 1 (more data from 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this to split it into the year, and everything else, if it's always a 4 digit year:

```
result = [(x[0:4], x[4:]) for x in data]
```

This just separates out the string into a list of tuples, where the first items is the year and the second is everything else. It avoids having to fire up a regex parser, which is overkill for something so basic.

Then sort it:

```
result.sort(key = lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
```

This sorts the list in place and tells it to use the first element of the tuple as the sort key. It reverses it to sort in descending order, since that is what you have in the example.

To put it back the way you have in the example output:

```
output = [' '.join(x) for x in result]
```

This takes the tuples and pastes them back into a single string, using a space as the separator.

If you really only want to take this input and print the sorted version, the answer by @samusa is the way to go. If you want to do any sort of additional manipulation of the data that requires it to be broken down into individual strings with the years separated out from the rest, then do it the way I described.

Answer (score 0):

On request to the comments about using split instead of regex.

You can split the strings by newline and sort in reverse order by the first word:

```py
strings = '2011 blah blah\n2016 blah blah'
parts = strings.split('\n')

result = sorted(parts, key=lambda a: a[:a.index(' ')], reverse=True)
print('\n'.join(result))
```

```
2016 blah blah
2011 blah blah
```